# Fragment won't display more than one item

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments

I have created an Android chat application which incorporates Firebase and created a fragment with a current users messages. The error occurs when a user sends a message to more than one person and the following image link shows how the first message is displayed whereas the most recent one is invisible. Does anyone know why this would be? I will include a few of my classes below.

My firebase is displayed as the following with messages containing first the user IDs, recipient IDs and then the unique message ID followed by the actual message and who sent it.

[image]

[image]

**Fragment Class**

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView convList;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private DatabaseReference userDatabase, messageDatabase;
private View view;

public ChatFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// Chat Fragment initialised
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);

    convList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.conv_list);
    convList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    convList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    String currentUser;
    currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    messageDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages").child(currentUser);
    messageDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    userDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    userDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    return view;
}

// Use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to populate each user of which messages have been sent between, the latest message sent between each user displayed, ordering the list by most recent message and the user's online status
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Query conversationQuery = messageDatabase.orderByChild("time");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserConversation, ConvViewHolder> friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserConversation, ConvViewHolder>(

            UserConversation.class,
            R.layout.activity_user_list,
            ConvViewHolder.class,
            conversationQuery

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ConvViewHolder friendsViewHolder, final UserConversation friends, int i) {

            final String user_id = getRef(i).getKey();

            Query lastMessageQuery = messageDatabase.child(user_id).limitToLast(1);

            // Retrieving data stored in Firebase for each message and its information
            lastMessageQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    String data = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                    ConvViewHolder.setMessage(data);

                    String time = dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue().toString();
                    ConvViewHolder.setTime(time);

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            userDatabase.child(user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                    String online = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();

                    friendsViewHolder.setName(userName);
                    friendsViewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());
                    friendsViewHolder.setUserOnline(online);

                    friendsViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Messenger.class);
                            intent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                            intent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                            try {
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                Log.i("Activity Not Found", "Error");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    };

    convList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);

}


public static class ConvViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    static View mView;

    public ConvViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public static void setMessage(String message){

        TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
        userStatusView.setText(message);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {

        TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
        userNameView.setText(name);

    }

    public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx) {

        CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);

    }

    public static void setTime (String time){
        TextView test = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.time_sent);
        test.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", Long.parseLong(time)));
    }

    public void setUserOnline(String online) {

        ImageView userOnlineView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_online_icon);

        if(online.equals("true")){

            userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {

            userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the error that you get and indicate the line at which it occurs.

Comment: No actual error occurs, the emulator runs yet for some reason it wont display more than one message within that fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in your code, you are using an older version of the `Firebase-UI` library, in which because of a bug, you explicitly don't need to use fixed size. In order to display the data in your `RecyclerView`, please remove/comment the following line of code:

```
convList.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Please see [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/204) more informations.

Comment: Just tried that, it still appears as in the image shown above. It seems unusual that it just displays one and not any more.

Comment: You are using `limitToLast(1)`. Can this be a reason why you are having only one message?

Comment: Originally I was using limitToLast to only show the most recent message for each user. I will try and remove it though and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: So you say that also without the limitation you are still geting only one message?

Comment: Yes, still getting the exact same.

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one message at that location?

Comment: If you want ill show you my firebase so you can see how it works. I am expecting for each item displayed above to be each user that the current user has sent a message to. The limitToLast should only show the latest message sent or received for each user.

Comment: Yes, you can add it to the original question.

Comment: As Isee, you get a single message because only one message you have in your database, right?

Comment: No, the amount of messages isn’t what I’m trying to display. Simply each item that is being displayed is each user which I have spoken to. In the message Firebase example, I have 2 users that I have spoken with, therefore it should be displaying those 2 users with the most recent message of both.

Comment: In this case, I'm afraid that you should make some changes in your schema. Maybe you should post another question with this exact problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your assistance. I’ll post another haha.